# VirtualBox doesn't capture USB drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox

I created a new Virtaul Box running 32 bit Windows 7 but the USB capture doesn't work.

When I capture the USB flash drive, it does set the check mark on it as captured but it never shows up in explorer (it does disappear from host).

I get a message on VM that `This device can perform faster` (screenshot below). When I click it, I get a message about USB host controller (screenshot below).

[image]
[image]

I went on to installed all windows updates in hopes it will fix the issues. I went into device manager to update the driver for USB Host controller but it says it has the latest. It does show a yellow mark on it as shown below but still says the driver is update-to-date.

[image]

Do I need to install a driver manually to fix this and if so which one?

Comment: In your settings for that VM, look in USB section, what type of USB controller is assigned to that VM?

Comment: @acejavelin I updated the post and added a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think you understand my request... Open Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager, select the VM you are using and then right-click on it and select Settings. Then in the next window, click USB on the right and look at the USB controller settings on the right. Please attach that information.

Comment: @acejavelin USB 1 was selected there, I changed it to 3 and it asks to install extension pack which I am going to try, should fix that  Will update.Thanks.

Comment: You should always install the extension pack... that is the drivers for the VirtualBox devices

Answer (score 0):

First, shutdown your VM and verify the USB controller type you have set for your VM. Open Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager, select the VM you are using and then right-click on it and select Settings. Then in the next window, click USB on the right and look at the USB controller settings on the right.

[image: VirtualBox Settings USB]

The controller type should be set to USB 2.0 or USB 3.0.

Next, start the VM and once it is up and running, open the menu at the top of the VM window or press RIGHT CTRL-HOME (default key combo) to access the menu, and select Devices, then `Insert Guest Additions CD image...` which should auto-start the application, if not, navigate to the optical drive in My Computer and right-click and select `Auto-play` or open the drive and run `VBoxWindowsAdditions` to run the Guest Additions Setup Wizard. This will install all the VirtualBox device specific drivers to your VM. A reboot of the VM is required after installation.

You should now be able to access your USB devices.

Comment: I forgot I already had guest additions installed and now having a weird problem that VM crashes when I start it after I set USB to to 2.0//3.0. It requires it but it seems its incompatible with current installed. I uninstalled the current though but stil same issue. VM woudn't start if USB is set to 2 or 3.

Comment: @zar disconnect any USB storage devices prior to starting the VM.

Comment: Removed them but mad no difference.

Comment: @zar Not sure what to tell you then, I literally did this on a Win7 VM that was at USB 1.0, changed it to 2.0 and booted fine and detected new hardware and root hub, then shutdown and changed it to 3.0 and booted and it did the same thing, detected new hardware and worked fine. Sounds like your issue isn't VirtualBox issue but something in your Windows setup inside the VM.

Comment: Yes its weird error, says `Implementation of the USB 2.0 controller not found!` when I start VM even though guest additions are installed.

Comment: In your screenshot, I don't see `Invalid settings detected" which shows up in my case just under the listview and left of `Ok` button if I selected USB 2.0 or 3.0

Comment: @zar You have conflicting options in your VM setup. Mouse over the Invalid Settings Detected in the window and it should tell you what is causing the conflict.

Comment: That's what it tells to `install extension pack..` which is installed but it doesn't seem to detect it.

Comment: @zar VirtualBox does not see the Guest Additions in the VM, most likely it either wasn't installed correctly or is the wrong version. Make sure you have the correct Guest Additions package in VB. Go to File - Preferences - Extensions and make sure the Guest Extensions pack versions matches your version of VirtualBox. You can also try to remove and reinstall the Guest Extensions in the VM.

Comment: That's an issue. File > Preferences -> Extensions list is empty. I obviously install it within the VM but it should show up here? Is there another way I can install extension pack?

Comment: @zar You install the Extension Pack in VirtualBox, then use use the option I noted in my answer to install the extension pack in the VM. You should never install the extension pack directly from the internet or another source inside the VM unless you know exactly what your doing and have a specific reason to do so.

Comment: But this fixed the VM. I downloaded and install extension pack on that screen so now it starts. However, it still does't capture the USB. Now it says `Device driver software was not successfully installed". Checking on this error now.